# bash "date" returns "invalid date" error for a specific date string

Tags: string, bash, date

I wanted to add one day to a date in bash using `date` command. The input format of date is like this : **20130101** which means **01 January 2013**

I use this command to accomplish that:

```
date -d "20130101 +1 day" +%Y%m%d
```

Everything went well till it reached this date: **20130322**

and then it returned this error:

```
date: invalid date ‘20130322 +1 day’
```

I tried the code with some other similar dates, some of them were fine and some were not! Is it normal? I mean maybe it is somehow related to numeral system converting like the one that happens when a for loop reach 9th loop. How can I properly workaround the problem?

Comment: It [works on my system](http://www.buildsonmymachine.com/)...

Comment: Show your full code. It works, just tried [this script](http://pastebin.com/GwyF42qA) and stopped it at 20670201...

Comment: No problem with RHEL6, RHEL7, Ubuntu 11.04 and Ubuntu 14.04.1. Reproducible with RHEL5 but with `date -d "20130101 +1 day" +%Y%m%d` and `date -d "20130322 +1 day" +%Y%m%d` with date command from GNU coreutils version 5.97.

Comment: @jm666 I tried your code, still the same on CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Works with `date (GNU coreutils) 8.23`... strange. I never would have thought that there may be such bug..

Comment: My ubuntu system is version 14.04 with the latest official updates (just checked) and my GNU coreutils reports itself as version 8.21

Comment: It works on Fedora 19 using GNU `date` 8.21 (the same as yours). Please include the **literal command** you run.

Comment: I wrote the exact command as you see in the main question

Comment: I very much doubt you wrote **the actual command**. You're not going to get an error message about `20130322` if you gave `20130101` to `date`.

Comment: This is the actual command, all I wanted to say is that it works for `20130101` as an example and not for `20130322`

Comment: Can you try `printf '%q\n'` in front of the full command? Then you should see any unprintable characters

Comment: I did, here is the output:
`date
-d
20130322\ +1\ day
+%Y%m%d`

Comment: @l0b0 I just tested the command on Debian wheezy with coreutils 8.13 on a new machine (AMD Processor) and got the same error! Now I'm sure that it is a bug, do you know where to report this?

Comment: Feel free to start a new bash with `bash --norc` and try again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason to the problem.

The problem is related to daylight saving time which is different for every time zone. So the error is expected to reproduce at different dates in respect to different time zones. More information can be found [here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#The-date-command-is-not-working-right_002e)

My time zone is IRST (+3:30) that, for example, is adjusted to forward one hour on 22 March 2013 (20130322), so the date command returns "Invalid Date" error for this date.
For solving the problem, as also mentioned in the provided link, you should provide time in addition of date, which is obviously should not be in the range of invalid time. Any time between 00:00:00 to 00:59:59 on 22 march will be invalid for my time zone and should be avoided. So for 22 March 2013 I can change the command this way to avoid the error:

```
date -d "20130322 12:00 +1 day" +%Y%m%d
```

Comment: In my case, I had to add my time zone as well (UTC-3). So, what worked for me was: `date -d "20170803 12:00 -0300 -1 day" +%Y%m%d`